# Insert key/id instead of value into SQL table

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

Sorry in advance, I am sure this question is answered somewhere but I'm not able to track down a solution. I am looking to insert records from a Pandas dataframe, storing events scraped from a webpage, into a normalized database. So my DF has records such as:

```
Time    Action      User    Company    User2
---------------------------------------------------
00:02   buy share   msmith  ACME       tjones
00:03   sell share  tjones  Alpha      msmith
...
```

and I have a database with tables:

```
ActionType (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR)

Users (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Username VARCHAR, CompanyID INT FOREIGN KEY)

Companies (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CompanyName VARCHAR)

Events (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ActionID INT FOREIGN KEY, UserID INT FOREIGN KEY, CompanyID INT FOREIGN KEY, User2ID INT FOREIGN KEY)
```

I want to insert the data frame into the events table, but I want it to store the associated ID for each column, rather than the raw text. Is there a way to easily do that through SQLAlchemy (or other RDBMS or ORM packages), or do I need to go row by row and set variables such as

```
userid = session.query(Users).filter(Users.Username == df.User)
```

Bonus (possibly separate) question, how would I go about entering a new value into the tables when it is encountered (i.e. df.User is not in Users table, so I want to `INSERT INTO Users VALUES` ...)

Comment: How are assigned the IDs? It matters if you want to be able to add new users, companies or actions.

Comment: the IDs are identity ids, so they are generated by the system

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate? [How to insert Python/Pandas data into a normalized database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728614/how-to-insert-python-pandas-data-into-a-normalized-database)