# How to insert Python/Pandas data into a normalized database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, database-normalization

Say I have a Pandas data frame with records such as:

```
Time    Action      User    Company    User2
---------------------------------------------------
00:02   buy share   msmith  ACME       tjones
00:03   sell share  tjones  Alpha      msmith
...
```

and I have a database with tables:

```
ActionType (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR)

Users (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Username VARCHAR, CompanyID INT FOREIGN KEY)

Companies (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CompanyName VARCHAR)

Events (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ActionID INT FOREIGN KEY, UserID INT FOREIGN KEY, CompanyID INT FOREIGN KEY, User2ID INT FOREIGN KEY)
```

I want to insert the data frame into the events table, but I want it to store the associated ID for each column, rather than the raw text. Is there a way to easily do that through SQLAlchemy (or other RDBMS or ORM packages), or do I need to go row by row and set variables such as

```
userid = session.query(Users).filter(Users.Username == df.User)
```

Alternatively, is the best way to handle this through the database? I could accomplish this by inserting the raw pandas data directly into a "staging" table, and then split the data points out into their respective tables using SQL.

That seems doable, I'm just looking to see if there is a more efficient solution through Python?

Bonus (possibly separate) question, how would I go about entering a new value into the tables when it is encountered (i.e. df.User is not in Users table, so I want to `INSERT INTO Users VALUES ...`)

Comment: If your source data does not already have surrogate key values and only has text values like 'buy share', 'sell share' then the only way you can determine if the value exists in the "ActionType" table is to look up its text value, so you might as well use that text value as a natural primary key instead of arbitrarily assigning an identity primary key.